# JSFiddle issue : Function Is Not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsfiddle

May be it's duplicate question,

i see every page on stack overflow, for this type of error.

but didn't get my solution.

Here is my fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/eua98tqa/6/

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="SeeChange" onClick="javascript:AddDate(Date(), 3);return false;" />
```

jQuery:

```
function AddDate(AddedDate, DateToBeAdded) {
    var result = new Date(AddedDate);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + DateToBeAdded);
    alert(result);
}
```

Note: works fine in my VS2015, FFConsole.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/80x9dkmh/, You need to select _No wrap - <in head>_ option. You should go through [jsFiddle Documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: thanks satpal... i found that option and now my code is working, you can add this as your answer and i upvote it..

Comment: If it helped you, mark it as a solution, not just upvote.

Comment: actually @Satpal solved my issue, but as Tosif get time to view and answer, i upvoted it..

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="SeeChange" onClick="javascript:AddDate(3);return false;" />
 <script>
  function AddDate(DateToBeAdded) {
    //setDate takes only one parameter
    var result = new Date();
    result.setDate(DateToBeAdded);
      alert(result)
    //o/p:Sun Apr 03 2016 12:05:20 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
  }
</script>
```